# Check if text from one dataframe exists in another dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I am new in working with text and nlp and now I have two dataframes like this (original are very large):

1. DF

| All_name | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| STEAM/BLIZZARD LLD -JOINT VENTURE | 2001-08-03 | Y |
| ACCO/SSD/HF CORP | 2020-03-03 | Y |
| ETIHAD/LUFTHANSA/HD LLC | 2018-01-12 | N |
| JOHN GROUP PLC/ROLLS-ROYCE PLC | 2005-12-19 | Y |
| FEDRA/KELL ELECTRONICS-STRATEGIC ALLIANCE | 1999-09-27 | N |
| CBC/MAFA STUDIOS {CBC/MAFA ENTERTAINMENT} | 2013-06-24 | N |

2. DF

| Company | another value |
| --- | --- |
| Soul Name Intertament | 50 |
| Etihad company | 300 |
| Rolls-Royce plc comp | 8 |
| Mafa corporation | 1000 |
| Aircorporation Lufthansa | 12 |
| Dll ltd | 18 |
| Airport Etihad | 1 |
| Hd corporation | 743 |

I need to check if there is a company in column "All_name" in DF1 from column "Company" in DF2.
The result have to be something like the new dataframe with values from DF2 if they are in DF1. With this example it looks like:

DF_result:

| Company | another value |
| --- | --- |
| Etihad company | 300 |
| Rolls-Royce plc comp | 8 |
| Mafa corporation | 1000 |
| Aircorporation Lufthansa | 12 |
| Airport Etihad | 1 |
| corporation Hd | 743 |

The difficult is in the difference between two columns in dataframes, only some words are similar. I have to compare words(?) or something else...

Comment: How about using `pd.merge` which basically can perform an inner/outer join. For eg: in your case, `result = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on='Company', right_on='All_name', how='inner')`. This, however, needs an exact text match between the columns so as to get the common data in both dataframes

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan text in columns is different, only some words are similar. I think it won`t work with this :(

Comment: Yes, string matching with partial words and expressions b/w data frames wouldn't be trivial

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan I understand, because of it I wrote examples :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for this dataset but be careful while using it on large dataset as it may give you some False positives as the data is quite messy:

```
df_1['All_name'] = df_1['All_name'].str.lower()
df_2['Soul Name Intertament'] = df_2['Soul Name Intertament'].str.lower()
all_companies = df_1['All_name'].str.split('/').explode().str.split(' ')

def apply_this(x):
    for company in all_companies:
        if len(set(x.split(' ')).intersection(set(company)))>=1:
            return True
    return False

df_result = df_2[df_2['Soul Name Intertament'].apply(lambda x: apply_this(x))]
print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
      Soul Name Intertament    50
0            etihad company   300
1      rolls-royce plc comp     8
2          mafa corporation  1000
3  aircorporation lufthansa    12
5            airport etihad     1
6            hd corporation   743
```

Comment: It is a good example, thank you, but I have a really big datasets. :(

Comment: then you should first apply some cleaning on your dataset